# AWS memcache throwing connection reset by peer error

Tags: python, memcached, elastic-cache

I am trying to connect to AWS memcache via lambda in python. When my cluster is having a single node. I am able to connect easily. But when my cluster is having multiple nodes, it is throwing **reset by peer** error.

I am using following code :

```
> nodes = elasticache_auto_discovery.discover(cluster_endpoint)
> nodes = map(lambda x: (x[1], int(x[2])), nodes)
> memcache_client = HashClient(nodes)
```

Can anyone help me here.